# how to remove unwanted characters from string in PHP

Tags: php

When i read an array i got value set like this `"lat" : -37.8087928,`. I want to only `-37.8087928` part. what is the correct way to do that.

I did it in this way:

```
$value = '"lat" : -37.8087928,';
$ex = explode(':', $value);
```

and

```
$ex2 = explode(',', $ex[1]);
```

final `resualt $ex2[0]`

is this correct or what is the correct way, thank you all

Comment: Do you get the correct result? Then it's the correct way. (you may have white-space trouble in the start of the string, though)

Comment: Of course, there are easier ways: e.g. preg_match()

Comment: This looks like JSON. How are you getting the array in the first place because there may be a far simpler way than extracting that JSON string then manipulating it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$value = '"lat" : -37.8087928,';
$final_value = preg_replace("/[^0-9.\-]/", "", $value);
```

The code above will strip all characters that are not numeric, dot or hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all spaces in a string

```
 $stingname=" test manish ";

    str_replace(" ","",$stingname);

    echo $stingname;
```

Result

```
testmanish
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question

Comment: by explode is the best way

Answer (score 0):

that's object notation. you might want to try

```
$locations = json_decode($value)
```

then you could access it like this:

```
echo $locations->lat; // prints -37.8087928
```

if you don't want to do that you could do:

```
$locationArray = explode($value, ':'); // returns [0: 'lat', 1: -37.8087928]
echo trim($locationArray[1]); // prints -37.8087928. trim to get rid of whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your approach. But you can use also this which is more easy to understand:

```
$value = '"lat" : -37.8087928,';
echo $float = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Hope this help you!

you can read more about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: This produces the WRONG result (32). While FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT gives the expected output, using filter_var is a messy solution - it's a blackbox whose function is far from clear.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method depends on the variability of the input string - "like this" is not an adequate explanation.

Your parser suffices - but has no error handling, nor any means of dealing with a differently formatted string. Using a regexp as described by jorge is more robust, however may not cope with some input scenarios.

The input string you provided looks very like JSON - in which case you should be using a JSON parser - PHP has a very good one built in - which will simply reject non-conformant input.

Answer (score 0):

People are suggesting regex's and explodes, why? Thats slow and not needed. If you have a fixed string, you can do it with some string functions:

```
$value = '"lat" : -37.8087928,';
$result = trim( substr($value, strpos($value,":")+1) ), " ,");
```

This works by finding the `:` in that string and substract it till the end. Then with a trim you remove the spaces and the comma. If the comma is ALWAYS there, you can do this, and drop the trim:

```
$result = substr($value, strpos($value,":")+1), -1 );// till -1 from the end
```